# PHP Twitter Trends

Tags: php, json, twitter

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\AppServ\www\twitter\index.php on line 4
```

http://pastebin.com/Sr5Ld6Vs

I'd like to TT print. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/FUzP4F

Perhaps it's due to extra whitespace? Try getting rid of those spaces in each blank line perhaps. I cannot see anything that would cause the error, there's no improper syntax and I cannot reproduce the error, but sometimes whitespace causes funky glitches in PHP.

Comment: @Mayk: What is still not working? I see some `Notice:`s, but I am not getting the same error you are.